# Incorrect shell output encoding

Tags: wifi, character-encoding, qt

I'm not an expert in Linux, but I am following the development of a software that runs on Linux Buildroot. The device can only use the program for the graphical interface, access the shell, or connect through a serial cable or SSH. The end-users of the device are given the option to connect to their Wi-Fi network.

The program is written in C++, and to perform the scanning and obtain the list of available Wi-Fi networks, a shell command is executed.

**My problem lies in the encoding of the result of this operation; I can't display accented characters correctly.**

In the program, I can enter a word with an accent and display it on the screen without any issues. However, when I retrieve the result from the shell command to get the Wi-Fi networks, I get an "incorrect" ESSID because if, for example, the network name contains the character `è`, I see its encoding as `\xC3\xA8`, and consequently, it is impossible to connect to the network.

I tried to encode the output of the command using a method, but it didn't work. I also ran the command I execute in the code directly in the shell, and the result was incorrectly encoded, as described above in the example. I deduced that it's a system issue, and I attempted to manually set the system encoding, but it didn't change anything.

I have noticed that some files are missing in the system I am using. Is there a solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

The pair of hex codes `0xC3` `0xA8` represents `è` in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. I suspect you're using the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding in your program (or a similar variant such as ISO-8859-15), where you would expect to see `0xA8` for the same character.

You'll need to adapt your program to handle UTF8 characters, or tell your Linux-based system to use ISO8850-1 encoding instead of UTF8.

Run this command on your Linux-based system to see what encoding it is configured to use as a default,

```
locale
```

On my system this reports that I'm using the UK (GB) English flavour of UTF-8,

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

And for my particular account I can identify that I am also using this locale setting with `env | grep -E 'LC_|LANG'`, which produces this output,

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

On a Debian-based system you should be able to change the system locale with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. This command also allows you to define additional locales available for use.

Comment: But it seems like my system isnt using LANG, as initially it was nowhere to be found, and even after I added it, nothing has changed.

Comment: @porrokynoa answer modified for the system default setting

Comment: Ok... But on my system locale not exists. My problem s that some files seem to be missing in the system, or at least if they are there, they are in a different location than usual.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you're going to need to adapt your program to support UTF-8

Comment: Initially, I wanted to encode the result from the code, but once I obtained the output, the code already recognizes it as UTF-8. Isn't there a way to execute the commands and set the encoding directly from the command? This way, we could bypass the system settings.

Comment: You've told me that the tools to change the locale aren't on your board. If you know a different way to change the locale, fine. But these days you should probably be writing for utf8 anyway

Comment: At the moment the only solution that could work in the best way would be to be able to solve the problem at the operating system level. Finding a code solution by adding controls that if in the tring of the result they are contained 'words' equivalent to coding codes did not inspire me as a better solution. I would spend to be able to add the coding directly to the command you use. If but it is not possible to make me arrange in the less clean way.

Comment: I would be surprised if your programming language didn't already have a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74684999/2344631) for handling UTF8. What you _should not do_ is build your own lookup/translation table

Comment: The problem does not go back to the programming language, I am using QT C ++. The problem lies in trying to translate the output.

Comment: If you use a utf8 aware library this is handled automatically

Comment: yes in theory, but since there is a conversion of the result in the middle when obtaining the output are already in utf-8, so I lose the codes because they are considered as reinforced characters